# What Layout is being used here?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

This is official PSG(Paris Saint-Germain) app. This is exactly same in android also but what I cant get is how they are creating this layout. There is a ImageView with textviews on it. I can do it but it uses a swipe gesture down to up which brings a text view with detail about the imagview with textview from below. And swiping from left to right changes news with exact same layouts.

So what are they using to create that layout? I know how to create each and every layout but i cannot connect them to each other. Mostly the textview which comes with swipe from down to up to each imageview. (Also are they using Activity or fragment for each news?)

[image: imageview]

[image: swiping up to get below imageview]

[image: imageview after completely swiping up]

[image: swiping from left to right to being another activity or fragment ?]

Comment: You can decompile the app and get the exact logic of creating such layouts. It will be good to do reverse engineering. You can directly see the XML file from layout folder and get the complete idea of how to create such layout.   https://stackoverflow.com/a/6081365/6587774

Comment: It looks like it might be React Native - does the iOS app look the exact same?

Comment: The bottom sliding up could be a bottomsheet. The views at the top could be an imageview and textview in a collapsing toolbar layout.

Comment: yes both are exactly same, leaving a few things out like animation in ios app are better but ui is exactly same in both ios and android

Comment: but can a toolbar also be slided from left to right to create a whole new activity? for eg- the image in which you see person and a media player is screen shot of siding between two "pages" those two are different.

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple ways to create such layout.

1. You can create this using a `FrameLayout` as root for all other `TextView`s and `ImageView`s. The white layout containing the text seems like a [bottomsheet](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-sheets.html). This approach might require more work to accomplish the results.
2. The better way would be using a constraint layout to spread out the views and constraint them to each-other. Added advantage would be better (and easier) [animations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8lAXJ5NFXTM) support and a more robust layout.